# Swift UIScrollViewDelegate not triggers scrollViewDidScroll event

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have two `UIScrollViews` in my `UIViewController` both of them have different properties such as `pagingEnabled`, `contentSize` & `contentInset` also i need them to behave separately when scrolling so i create two separate custom classes like below.

```
class NavigationScrollView: UIScrollView{

}

class ContentScrollView: UIScrollView{

}
```

also delegates

```
extension NavigationScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    // this method not triggers
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }
}
extension ContentScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    // this method not triggers
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }    
}
```

In main `viewController` `viewDidLoad()` i do

```
navigationScroller = NavigationScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frameWidth, 40.0))
contentScroller = ContentScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frameWidth, frameHeight))
```

Comment: Have you assigned `delegate` property of scroll view?

Comment: no because i don't know hot to assign delegate to custom class.

Comment: i done `navigationScroller.delegate = self` but it didn't work.

Comment: I am not sure why did you write it separately? I mean why did you leave out UIScrollView inheritance in second code you've listed? Your class should be declared like `class NavigationScroller: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: @Uros19 It's a good coding practice, separating makes the code more clearly.

Comment: Why did you `class NavigationScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate` and `class ContentScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate` ? Why no extension? For example `extension ContentScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate` and 'extension NavigationScrollView: UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: sorry it's a mistake,  i forgot to put `extension `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about you assign the delegate this way?

```
    class NavigationScrollView: UIScrollView{
        override func didMoveToSuperview() {
            super.didMoveToSuperview()
            self.delegate = self
        }
    }

    class ContentScrollView: UIScrollView{
        override func didMoveToSuperview() {
            super.didMoveToSuperview()
            self.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it make sense when the scrollview subclasses being delegate? I thought the advantage of delegation is that one class is working for another.

Comment: @Areal-17 Yes, you are right. It's a problem, maybe use KVO is better when delegate may be re-assigned.

Comment: The right thing to do is to simply implement the delegate in the controller or similar.